# is it necessary to explicitly define the belongsTo variable as grails domain property?

Tags: grails

I am wondering what is the difference between these two definitions:

```
class Book{

        String title
        Author author   
        static belongsTo = [author: Author]

    }



class Book {
   String title
   static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

My doubt is whether explicitly declaring variable as in the first example is optional or is the first definition different from the second definition? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, but it's not obvious why. In the second example, even though you don't declare an `Author` property, one is there because Grails uses an AST transform to add the property for you. The `belongsTo` property is a map; the key (`author`) is used as the variable name and the value is used as the type. So the `Author author` property in the first example is redundant because it would have been added for you at compile time.

It doesn't hurt to include it and could help an IDE that isn't very Grails-aware with autocompletion.

Similarly, Grails adds `Long id` and `Long version` properties (omitting the version if you have `version false` in the `mapping` block) so you can add them to your code but they'd also be redundant. Of course if you need to change the type of the id you would be explicit.

If you have a `hasMany` property in the `Author` class, e.g.

```
static hasMany = [books: Book]
```

Grails will also add in a property based on that declaration. Again the property is a map, and the value specifies the type of the collection elements, and the key specifies the property name. So in effect you get a

```
Set<Book> books
```

property. You can add this to your code (typically without the generic type, `Set books`) but it's unnecessary since most IDEs know what Grails adds.

You would add that property to your code if you want to change from the default `Set` type to a `List`:

```
List books
```

but only if it makes sense to order them in the database.

Note that these variable names are just conventions. You can name the `Author` and books properties however you like, e.g.

```
static belongsTo = [writer: Author]
```

which would add a `Author writer` property, and

```
static hasMany = [tomes: Book]
```

which would add a `Set tomes` property.

Answer (score 2):

The end result is the same on the database level - book table will have an `author_id` column as the foreign key for `author` table.

`belongsTo` - sets the cascading behavior for saving/deleting and provides a back reference to author, so you can do `bookInstance.author`